# Create table statement with repeated nested column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, data-structures, google-bigquery

I would like to create a table with 2 columns:

- `name` as `string`
- `info` as repeated struct containing:

  - `key` as `string`
  - `value` as `float64`

Can I do it with `create table` statement?

Then I would like to insert a record:

```
'John', [{'key': 'a', 'value': 0.7}, {'key': 'b', 'value': 0.8}, {'key': 'c', 'value': 1.2}]
```

Can that be done with `insert into` statement?

Comment: type of Database? MYSQL? SQL? NoSQL?

Comment: I had it only in a tag, sorry.

Comment: Tagging your database is the correct and most concise way to convey that information, Matt. @AlbertoSinigaglia, the tags are part of the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

1 - to create table

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.newtable   
(   
  name STRING,   
  info ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value FLOAT64>>   
)
```

2 - to insert data

```
INSERT dataset.newtable   
VALUES ('John', [('a', 0.7), ('b', 0.8), ('c', 1.2)])
```

Note: above can be done in one "shot" as in below example

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.newtable AS
SELECT 'John' AS name, [STRUCT<key STRING, value FLOAT64>('a', 0.7), ('b', 0.8), ('c', 1.2)] info
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to create a sort of Master/Details structure. Supposing you are using a relational database, I suggest not use a single table but two separate tables.

**First table (we can name it "Person")**

- `id` as `int64` (primary key)
- `name` as `string`

**Second table (we can name it "Info")**

- `id` as `int64` (primary key)
- `key` as `string`
- `value` as `int64`
- `personid` as `int64` (foreign key on Person.id)

So you can `insert into` the "Info" table.